# How to load Additional Pages for Twitter Hashtag Search using JSON

Tags: json, search, twitter, paging, hashtag

I'm using the Twitter URL: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23test in order to return a JSON list of tweets with the hash tag #Test.

It returns 15 results and says page 1.  How do I load the next page of 15 tweets?

*I tried adding &page=2 to the search URL, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON response of the URI you posted includes the query parameters to use to get the next page.  It's in the "next_page" element.  Currently, the value is "?page=2&max_id=80076124637499392&q=%23test".  So, the complete URI for the second page is http://search.twitter.com/search.json?page=2&max_id=80076124637499392&q=%23test

[The Twitter search API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) unfortunately does not describe how to use this parameter, though it is briefly described in the Twitter API Wiki at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554664/Return-Values.